# Need a common mongodb connection for every module in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am  working on a task with different modules.

I require a common mongodb connection for each and every module..

How can I write in some module and use in this because the db connection is also required in some other modules...

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
var dbo;
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  dbo = db.db("mydb");
});

router.post('/', function(req, res) {

    dbo.collection("customers").find({"userid":req.body.userid}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if(result.length>0){
        res.send("username already taken please enter differnt username ")
    }

    else if(req.body.fname==undefined||(!validator.isAlpha(req.body.fname))){
    res.send("please enter only alphabets as fname ")
   }

   else if(req.body.lname==undefined||(!validator.isAlpha(req.body.lname))){
    res.send("please enter only alphabets as lname ")
   }

   else if(req.body.userid==undefined||(!validator.isAlphanumeric(req.body.userid))){
    res.send("please enter only alphanemric as user name ")
   }

    else if(req.body.pwd==undefined||req.body.pwd.length<6){
    res.send("please enter atleast  6 charcaters as password ")
   }

   else{
            var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
            var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
            var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.pwd, salt);
            req.body.pwd=hash;


        dbo.collection("customers").insertOne(req.body, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 document inserted");
        });
        res.send(req.body);
    }

 });


    });



module.exports = router;
```

Comment: have you tried my answer below ?

Comment: actaully i am not aware of the concepts that you used so i am going through it and i will try it and i will reply to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
var dbo=null;

exports.conection=function(){
    if(dbo!=null) return 

  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
   dbo = db.db("mydb");


});
}


exports.get = function (){
    return dbo;
}
```

i tried this and i use get method when ever i require this is working for me

Answer (score 0):

use can use node export and import, to that you can use mongodb connection instance in other modules also,
assuming dbo is variable where you want to store mongodb connection

```
export let dbo;
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
if (err) throw err;
dbo = db.db("mydb");
});
```

you can assign db connection to dbo variable and and use it in whichever module you want

Comment: i have used this but it is not working can you please add me a few details how to use this in the other nodule ...i am asking about how should we can use dbo value in other modules can we use directly or else we need to  import or require any files for that

Comment: (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export let dbo;
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

Comment: let dbconnection  = require('filename.js')
import the file, and by using dbconnection.dbo you can get the mongodb instance,

Comment: thanks for your reply but still it is not working let dbconnection = require('mongo.js')
^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Comment: just try ,let dbconn = require('./mongo.js')
just check if the path of you are giving to require is correct
it should be respect to the directory

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/ take a look at it ,might help

Comment: sorry to say its not woring same error let dbconnection = require('./mongo.js')
^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Comment: try changing the export let dbo to export var dbo

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a middleware for your connection and then assign the `db` object to your request object ( `req` in your case )

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

router.use( (req,res,next) => {
   MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
     if (err) throw err;
     req.dbo = db.db("mydb");
     next();
  });
})
```

in your `router.post("/", ...)` you will do `req.dbo.collection(...)`